# TableView Static cells and iboutlet

Tags: static, tableview, cells, iboutlet

Trying to get my head around static cells in tableviews and adding iboutlets. When using static custom cells, whenever I try to add an iboutlet the only options I get when ctrl-click-drag are 'action' with object 'exit'. I want to add a iboutlet reference. Can I not do this with Static cells??

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the StoryBoard and click on the TableViewController. You just have to set the Class attribute as the name of your Class that you are using which inherits from UITableViewController.

After that, you will be able to add the @IBOutlets.